# how to change image button inside a tableviewCell without using tag

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a button in a tableview cell. I want that initially the button has an image "A", when the user clicks on it, it changes to "B", when the user clicks on it again it changes back to "A".

Let the two images be "A" and "B" in this scenario
I am unable to use `tag` because  I am using it to determine which button the user clicked using `indexPath.row`

below is the current state of my button function.

```
@IBAction func setNotification(sender: UIButton!) {

        cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! CustomTableViewCell

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "B")!, forState: .Normal)
currentRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude ,longitude:longitude), radius: 10, identifier: "xyz")
```

Also this is how my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`function looks

```
cell.notifybutton.addTarget(self, action: "setNotification:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.notifybutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "A"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.notifybutton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: So what is not working now ?

Comment: @JulianM after the image is changed to "B", i want it to change back to "A" when the user taps the button again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You change button image without using tag follow this code.

Your cellForRowAtIndexPathfunction set two button image for different state

```
cell.notifybutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "A"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
cell.notifybutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "B"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
cell.notifybutton.selected = false //default A image display
```

the your button clicked method

```
@IBAction func setNotification(sender: UIButton!) {
    if (sender.selected)
    {
         sender.selected = false
    }
    else
   {
        sender.selected = true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

you should use below code

```
- (void)btnChangeImage {
    UIButton *btn;

    if (btn.selected) {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    } else {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"diselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cell.notifybutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "A"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
cell.notifybutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "B"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
cell.notifybutton.selected = false //default A image display